# Superscript prime symbol

Tags: syntax, symbolic

`x\[Prime]` looks like $x_{'}$, ugly right?
Is there a way to make a symbol with prime to look like $x'$?

---

That's what I'm trying right now:

```
Notation[ x_', Primed[x_]]
Primed[x_] := Symbol[SymbolName[x] <> "\[Prime]"]
```

But how then I use it in patterns? If I do this:

```
f[q_, q':_] := q + q'
```

Weird syntax errors appear:

```
Syntax::sntxf: "T[r_," cannot be followed by "q':_]".
Syntax::tsntxi: "q':_" is incomplete; more input is needed.
Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .
```

If we replace `q':_` with `Pattern[q',_]` another error:

```
Pattern::patvar: "First element in pattern Pattern[q',_] is not a valid pattern name. "
```

But `Head[q']` returns `Symbol` and `Pattern` requires a `Symbol` as first parameter.

What is wrong?

Comment: Why not type `x'`?

Comment: @rm-rf Because it will be a derivative then and not a symbol.

Comment: Ah, you want to be able to do things like $x^\prime=3$, then?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, but without `Needs["Notation\`"];Symbolize[x']`.

Comment: Actually I can't even symbolize a symbol with prime like this, I was sure that would work.

Comment: Very closely related: [How to Clear variables with apostrophe?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15613/245) There, I suggest using a different unicode glyph that looks better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment to the question, I think the best solution is to use a Unicode character (see also the answer by The Vee). Here is a modified version of my earlier answer:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAliases -> 
  DeleteDuplicates@
   Join[{"'" -> FromCharacterCode[700]}, 
    InputAliases /. 
      Quiet[Options[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases]] /. 
     InputAliases -> {}]]

eʼ = 1

(* ==> 1 *)

eʼʼ = 2

(* ==> 2 *)

eʼ + eʼʼ

(* ==> 3 *)
```

The only modification is that I defined the shortcut so that you can now really enter the prime by typing the actual prime symbol on the keyboard, just surrounded by escape, i.e., <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.

As you can see in the example, the input alias immediately converts this to primed variable names, which can be used like any other symbol.

Answer (score 12):

This is following Jens's suggestion to use a different Unicode glyph, but different from the answer linked in the corresponding comment. We can use Unicode directly, so let's just find a [letter-like modifier glyph](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lm/list.htm) that looks good. A quick search for "prime" gives a nice solution in [MODIFIER LETTER PRIME](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02b9/index.htm). You can type it using the notation `\:02b9` which renders as `ʹ`, or just copy and paste the character itself:

[image]

This does not require *any* packages or prior code.

Closely related `\:02c8` and `\:02ca` are also options and work just as well, the choice is a matter of preference.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my answer (+1) - I think I'll re-post it here with a modification that would make typing even easier...

Comment: @Jens Oh, mine is more similar than I originally thought. Only now I noticed that your constant `700` is simply `0x2bc` and thus `FromCharacterCode[700] = \:02bc`, just a different one from the same list. I did not understand that the code is there just to simplify the keyboard input, I thought it was using some sort of invisible surrogate.

Answer (score 10):

This is not really ideal, but it gets you most of the way there:

```
SetAttributes[makeSuperscript, HoldAllComplete];
makeSuperscript[sym_Symbol] := (
   sym /: MakeBoxes[sym, form_] = With[{name = SymbolName[sym]},
     InterpretationBox[SuperscriptBox[name, "\[Prime]"], sym]
    ];
   sym
  );

makeSuperscript[q]
(* -> InterpretationBox[SuperscriptBox["q", "\[Prime]"], q] *)
```

The symbol is still called `q`, but it now looks like $q'$, as the `InterpretationBox` is not visible. You can either copy and paste the superscripted form (to make assignments, or use in other expressions) or enter it as `q`, as you prefer.

Comment: But I want to have this notation inside input, mostly in patterns, so that functions like `f[x'_] := x'` would work. Basically I want `\[Prime]` to be higher.

Comment: @swish after evaluating `makeSuperscript[x]`, `f[x_] := x` displays in the way that you want. If you copy and paste the output of `Information[f]`, it works as input, even in a new session. I know this is not quite how you envisioned this working, but unfortunately I'm not aware of any reasonably safe way of accomplishing that. Even if you use a different font that has a higher-up `\[Prime]`, you'll still need a `StyleBox` for it to display as such unless you edit the font mapping file `UnicodeFontMapping.tr`.

Comment: That causes `q` to display as `q^\[Prime]`. But you could instead use `InterpretationBox[SuperscriptBox[name, "\[Prime]"], 
 Symbol[name <> "\[Prime]"]]`.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail yes, that's right, but the point was to have a symbol that *appeared* to be primed without having to have `'` or `\[Prime]` in its actual name due to likely confusion (of both the user and *Mathematica* itself) with `Derivative[1]`. If you *really* want `\[Prime]` in the name then yes, your suggestion is sensible. One could also use any other Unicode character that displays in approximately the right way.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: The `Derivative` confusion only occurs with an apostrophe, not `\[Prime]`. The asker wanted to be able to use unprimed and primed in the same expression.

Answer (score 6):

This is an unashamed variation on @Oleksandr R's post but prompted by the OP comment "*Basically I want `\[Prime]` to be higher.*"

Using adjustment boxes you can position the prime exactly where you want. Easiest way to do set the position is probably to type `x\[Prime]` and go to the menu **Insert** > **Typesetting** and nudge the prime around.

[image]

```
SetAttributes[higherPrime, HoldAllComplete];

higherPrime[
   sym_Symbol] := (sym /: MakeBoxes[sym, form_] = 
    With[{name = SymbolName[sym]}, 
     RowBox[{name, 
       AdjustmentBox["\[Prime]", BoxBaselineShift -> -0.9, 
        BoxMargins -> {{-0.15, 0}, {0, -0}}]}]];
   sym);
```

[image]

Comment: The main problem is that `FullForm[higherPrime[x]]` is stil `x`, so it's impossible to use both primed and unprimed versions of one symbol. Nudge Up is a great suggestion, what we need now is the way to automate it.

Answer (score 2):

In *Mathematica* 10 using

```
<< Notation`
Notation[x' => xPrime]
```

seems to work to "disconnect" x' from its meaning as a derivative. (Note- the Notation text used here represents entering using the Notation Palette. *Mathematica* interprets this to

```
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
   RowBox[{"x", "'"}]] \[DoubleLongRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper["xPrime"]
]
```

but no reason to do that by hand )

Comment: Trying the first two lines, I get a `Notation::noexbtag` error. (V10.0.1)

Comment: NB: This only worked for me when I reproduced the second line with the Notation Palette.