# 3rd derivative keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, free-form-input

For a long time i've evaluated `D[f[t],{t,3}]` to get this power-like derivative thing:

$$f^{(3)}(x)$$

Is it possible to obtain same through an easier keyboard shortcut?

Comment: `f'''[t]` ?????

Comment: yes i know, but i mean without evaluation needed, like for second derivative, f ctrl+6 esc ' ' esc

Comment: `Derivative[3][f][x]` then Ctrl + Shift + n?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: My interpretation of your question:**

From the clarification in your comment to the question:

> like for second derivative,  `f`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`6`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`''`<kbd>Esc</kbd>

I assume you want the analogous entry method for the third derivative as you demonstrated for the second derivative. The difference to the other entry methods is that it uses the special character `\[DoublePrime]` in the input, as a *superscript*. That's very different from the input method using simply `f'''[x]` where the character `'` is repeated three times.

**End edit**

This works by setting an `InputAlias` for the unicode character of the triple prime so that you can enter it as <kbd>ESC</kbd>'''<kbd>ESC</kbd>, and then setting `$PreRead` to translate triple primes in superscript boxes before they get converted to `Power`:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAliases -> 
  Join[Quiet@
     OptionValue[Options[EvaluationNotebook[]], InputAliases] /. 
    InputAliases -> {}, {
    "'''" -> FromCharacterCode[8244]}]]

$PreRead = ReplaceAll[#, SuperscriptBox[f_, "‴"] :> RowBox[
      {
       RowBox[{"Derivative", "[", "3", "]"}], "[", f, "]"}]] &;

f[x_] := x^4

f‴[z]

(* ==> 24 z *)

g‴[x]
```

> $g^{(3)}[x]$

The example code above can't be copied directly: you have to enter the triple primes as *superscripts*, i.e., `f`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`6`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`'''`<kbd>Esc</kbd>

A similar alias definition using Unicode was done in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15626/245).